# How to drag and drop an enum in Xcode, Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I've got a simple `enum` as my data-structure for two `UICollectionView`:

```
enum ToolBarItem {
    case inking(PKInkingTool.InkType, UIColor, CGFloat)
    case lasso
    case eraser(PKEraserTool.EraserType)
}
```

both the `UICollectionView` models are just:

```
private(set) var tools = [ToolBarItem]()
```

I want to be able to drag and drop the items within and between two `UICollectionView` and thus I need to turn this into a dragItem somehow.

---

I've read about embedding my `enum` in a class and implementing `NSItemProviderWriting`, `NSItemProviderReading` and `Codable` in order to create an item-provider. But this is very messy and I hope that there is a better solution for this since it is just a single `enum`.

I'd be very happy to receive any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no answers yet I wanted to share my current solution for people with the same problem:

I've created a class called `dummyToolItem` which conforms to `NSItemProviderWriting` and `NSItemProviderReading`. The implementations are not functional though and they don't need to be as they will never be used.

I create my `UIDragItem` like this now:

```
let toolData = toolBarItems.tools[indexPath.item] // this is the ToolBarItem
let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider(object: dummyToolItem()))
dragItem.localObject = toolData
return [dragItem]
```

Since only my local `UICollectionView` will accept this data and use `localObject` the dummy Implementation is unimportant and can still be used to identify that the type is a `ToolBarItem`.

I would imagine there is a better way of doing this but this solution works.